# extract record on basis of date span

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I have 2 tables MEMBEN and MEMELIG, data is as below.

MEMBEN details:
[image]

MEMELIG details:

[image]

i want to join two tables in such way that it does not give cartesian product but selective data on basis of datespan of Benefit eff and benefit end date, so consider for above example we take member with id = '1001',

below picture contains all details which i am looking for.

Expected result details

[image]

Please help on this i tried using WITH clause but not able to proceed with result.

Comment: I know the below query is one solution :
select A.MEMBER_ID,A.NAME,A.BENEFIT_EFF_DT,A.BENEFIT_END_DT,B.LIS_EFF_DT,B.LIS_END_DT,B.LIS_CO_PAY from 
MEMELIG A inner join MEMBEN B on A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID where A.MEMBER_ID = '1001' and LIS_EFF_DT between

 BENEFIT_EFF_DT and BENEFIT_END_DT
and LIS_END_DT between BENEFIT_EFF_DT and BENEFIT_END_DT but i need one generic query using with clause so that if more than one conditions encountered then can modify the subquery of with clause without impacting current query.

Comment: Do **not** put code or additional information in comments. **[Edit]** your question and add the code as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Answer (score 0):

Looking into you sample data, it seems that you are looking for something like below.

```
SELECT m1.member_id
    ,lis_eff_dt
    ,lis_end_dt
    ,benefit_eff_dt
    ,benefit_end_dt
FROM memben m1
INNER JOIN memlig m2 ON m1.member_id = m2.member_id
    AND m1.member_id = '1001'
    AND m1.lis_eff_dt >= m2.benefit_eff_dt
    AND m1.lis_end_dt <= m2.benefit_end_dt;
```

The cte version can be.

```
WITH cte (
    member_id
    ,lis_eff_dt
    ,lis_end_dt
    ,benefit_eff_dt
    ,benefit_end_dt
    )
AS (
    SELECT m1.member_id
        ,lis_eff_dt
        ,lis_end_dt
        ,benefit_eff_dt
        ,benefit_end_dt
    FROM memben m1
    INNER JOIN memlig m2 ON m1.member_id = m2.member_id
        AND m1.member_id = '1001'
        AND m1.lis_eff_dt >= m2.benefit_eff_dt
        AND m1.lis_end_dt <= m2.benefit_end_dt
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

You can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/JXBN90217)**

Comment: @MohdShariq: Kindly read [**Acepting and upvoting Answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :-)